# Progressing matplotlib FuncAnimation with button_press_event

Tags: matplotlib, events

I'm trying to register a `button_press_event` to an `on_click` function that's used to progress the frames of the `animate` function used by `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`.

The problem is that the `print` inside `on_click` never happens. I suppose the issue is that the loop used to halt animating until the `button_press_event` is detected is locking the interpreter.

```
data = [
    {'1': [(2000, 2000), (2050, 2000), (2050, 2100)],
     '2': [(1500, 1500), (1550, 1500), (1550, 1600)],
     '3': [(1700, 1700), (1750, 1700), (1750, 1850)],
    },
    {'1': [(4000, 2000), (5000, 2000), (6000, 2010)],
     '2': [(4500, 1500), (4505, 1500), (3505, 1510)],
     '3': [(4700, 1700), (6705, 1700), (5705, 1710)],
    },
    {'1': [(3300, 1000), (4080, 4000), (4000, 5010)],
     '2': [(3500, 3200), (3505, 2750), (2505, 1910)],
     '3': [(3700, 2600), (4705, 4100), (3705, 1310)],
    }
]


plots = {k: ax.plot([],[])[0] for d in data for k in d.keys()}

progress = False
def on_click(event):
    print('Event')
    global progress
    progress ^= True

def animate(i):
    d = data[i]

    while not progress:
        pass

    plots[k].set_data(list(zip(*v))) for k,v in d.items()]

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(data), interval=1000, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I suppose `while not progress:` is meant to be `if not progress:`? Though I'm not sure what the overall aim of this code would be

Comment: every second, update the plots -- if there has been no button event, wait indefinitely before updating the plots

Comment: This translates pretty much into "Do nothing unless a button is pressed. If a button is pressed, update the chart." which in turn means you do not need any animation at all. Seems like the answer below also understood it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you are using an Animation at all.
Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
    {'1': [(2000, 2000), (2050, 2000), (2050, 2100)],
     '2': [(1500, 1500), (1550, 1500), (1550, 1600)],
     '3': [(1700, 1700), (1750, 1700), (1750, 1850)],
     },
    {'1': [(4000, 2000), (5000, 2000), (6000, 2010)],
     '2': [(4500, 1500), (4505, 1500), (3505, 1510)],
     '3': [(4700, 1700), (6705, 1700), (5705, 1710)],
     },
    {'1': [(3300, 1000), (4080, 4000), (4000, 5010)],
     '2': [(3500, 3200), (3505, 2750), (2505, 1910)],
     '3': [(3700, 2600), (4705, 4100), (3705, 1310)],
     }
]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plots = {k: ax.plot([], [])[0] for d in data for k in d.keys()}
current_frame = 0
max_frames = len(data)


def on_click(event):
    print('Event')
    global current_frame
    current_frame = (current_frame + 1) % max_frames
    d = data[current_frame]
    [plots[k].set_data(list(zip(*v))) for k, v in d.items()]
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale()
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
plt.show()
```